# Java regex pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string of the following format:

```
String name = "A|DescA+B|DescB+C|DescC+...X|DescX+"
```

So the repeating pattern is **?|?+**, and I don't know how many there will be. The part I want to extract is the part before |...so for my example I want to extract a list (an ArrayList for example) that will contain:

```
[A, B, C, ... X]
```

I have tried the following pattern:

```
(.+)\\|.*\\+
```

but that doesn't work the way I want it to? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consuming any character (`.`) and that includes the `|` so, the parser goes on munching everything, and once it's done taking any char, it looks for `|`, but there's nothing left.

So, try to match any character *but* `|` like this:

```
"([^|]+)\\|.*\\+"
```

And if it fits, make sure your all-but-| is at the beginning of the string using `^` and that there's a + at the end of the string with `$`:

```
"^([^|]+)\\|.*\\+$"
```

UPDATE: Tim Pietzcker makes a good point: since you are already matching until you find a `|`, you could just as well match the rest of the string and be done with it:

```
"^([^|]+).*\\+$"
```

UPDATE2: By the way, if you want to simply get the first part of the string, you can simplify things with:

```
myString.split("\\|")[0]
```

Comment: Actually, you can drop the `\\|` (if there is at least one `|` in the string).

Answer (score 3):

To convert this into a list you can do like this:

```
String name = "A|DescA+B|DescB+C|DescC+X|DescX+";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^|]+)\\|.*?\\+").matcher(name);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
}
```

This gives you the list:

```
[A, B, C, X]
```

Note the `?` in the middle, that prevents the second part of the regex to consume the entire string, since it makes the `*` *lazy* instead of *greedy*.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: Find all characters between `+` (or start of string) and `|`:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|[+])[^|]+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to split by `\\+`, then for each part apply the `(.+?)\\|.*` pattern to extract the group you need.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I also need to validate that the string has that format...so I wanted to do it with pure regex.